# Could anyone please explain how below code work? Group adjacent list. Python

Tags: python, zip

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]  
group_adjacent = lambda a, k: zip(*([iter(a)] * k)) 
print(list(group_adjacent(a, 3))) # [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
print(list(group_adjacent(a, 2))) # [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
print(list(group_adjacent(a, 1))) # [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,), (6,)]
```

I have a hard time figuring out how above code works.

I understand that *([iter(a)] * k) is doing a tuple unpacking.

iter(a) will return an iterator for the given list a.

[iter(a)] seems to put the iterator into a list.

I can print out what is in it using below code. But I am stuck there. I appreciate any input.

```
for x in [iter(a)]:
    for y in x:
        print(y)
```

Comment: The important thing is that `[iter(a)] * k` returns a list with `k` references to *the same* iterator. So each time that zip gets a value from each of them, it gets consecutive values from `a`.

Comment: Compare and contrast: `list(zip(*([iter(a)]*3)))` and `list(zip(*([iter(a) for _ in range(3)])))`

Answer (score 1):

It's a little tricky and the behavior may not be immediately obvious, so using this code could get confusing...

```
iter(a)
```

Returns iterator for `a`.

```
[iter(a)]
```

Creates a list containing single item, this iterator.

```
[iter(a)] * k
```

produces the list with **the same** (this is important) iterator being repeated `k` times.

```
*([iter(a)] * k)
```

Is passing all items (iterators) from that list as individual arguments to `zip`:

```
zip(*([iter(a)] * k))
```

So `zip` works on entries of `k` copies of the same iterator... and since it's still that one same object... Each `.__next__()` advances the iteration thereof.

In other words it would be the same as for instance for `k` of value `3`:

```
i = iter(a)
zip(i, i, i)
```

where each `i` argument is being accessed, and next item is being retrieved, advancing the `i` iterator every time.